# TastyPie ManyToMany not working

Tags: django, python-2.7, tastypie

I have been trying to get a ManyToMany working in TastyPie, but th e link just fails to show up. Its a simple relationship, a Family record with multiple address records, but when I display a family record via the api, address just doesn't show, as though the field and relationship doesn't exit.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
class Family(models.Model):
    ''' This is the Family Object table .
    Contacts link to this table, but this table has a many to many relationship
    with the addresses '''
    FamilyName = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Address = models.ManyToManyField('Address')
    Active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.FamilyName

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['FamilyName']

class Address(models.Model):
    ''' This table hold all the addresses for families, contacts and staff.

    All contact detail should be here, phones, addresses, postal titles etc
    are stored in these records
     '''
    HomeSalutation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    PostalTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    AddressLine1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    AddressLine2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    AddressLine3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    AddressLine4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    PostCode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    Phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    Phone3 = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    EmailAddress = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    Note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s , %s' % (self.PostalTitle, self.PostCode)

    def ListAddress(self):
        returnAddress=''
        if self.AddressLine1:
            returnAddress+=self.AddressLine1
        if self.AddressLine2:
            returnAddress+=', %s' % (self.AddressLine2)
        if self.AddressLine3:
            returnAddress+=', %s' % (self.AddressLine3)
        if self.AddressLine4:
            returnAddress+=', %s' % (self.AddressLine4)
        if self.PostCode:
            returnAddress+=', %s' % (self.PostCode)
        return returnAddress

class AddressResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset=Address.objects.all()
        resource_name='address'
        filtering = {
            "HomeSalutation":ALL,
            "PostalTitle": ALL,
            "AddressLine1": ALL,
            "AddressLine2": ALL,
            "AddressLine3": ALL,
            "AddressLine4": ALL,
            "PostCode": ALL,
            "Phone1" : ALL,
            "Phone2": ALL,
            "Phone3": ALL,
            "Active": ALL,
        }
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        cache=SimpleCache()

class FamilyResource(ModelResource):
    Address = fields.ToManyField('AddressResource','Address',null=True,full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset=Family.objects.filter(Active=True)
        resource_name='family'
        filtering = {
            "id" : ALL,
            "FamilyName" : ALL,
        }
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        cache=SimpleCache()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TastyPie is picky about exposing foreign keys. I suggest zapping the `FamilyResource.Address` reference, then re-add it using code from the tutorial.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-more-resources

Comment: I'm not really why any of this worked, but it did. I removed the Address ToManyField line and refreshed the server.

I then added the code for Foreign Key which failed as this is a ManyToMay.

I then changed this to ToManyField and while for field was visible in the returned data, it was empty, so I added full=True

Now it is working, even though I tried the same code before.

Thus it is now working, but I don't know why

Comment: @user2244190: yes :)  If you would, please select my answer as "accepted"